# find output with a title as pipe

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I try to get a listing from an directory with mod time and send this per pipe to mail command

so I fiddled this construct together:

```
find /etc/myfolder -type f -exec sh -c 'printf "%-40s %s\n" $(echo {}|sed "s:/etc/myfolder::g") "$(stat -c %y {})" ' \; | mail -a "FROM: Server <root@server.com>" -a "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" -s "test" my@domain.com
```

Now I want that I have a title line on top - but don’t know how.

```
printf "%-40s %s\n" File Mod | find ....
```

This cant work, because find don't forward it to the next pipe.

Any Idea how to do it? I know it is possible that I write the content first to a file and pipe later this file content to mail, but that's not what I want to do.

I prefer a oneliner :)

OK, this is now the working example I use in crontab:

```
(printf "\%-40s \%s\n" File Mod; find /etc/folder -type f -exec sh -c 'printf "\%-40s \%s\n" $(echo {}|sed "s:/etc/folder/::g") "$(stat -c \%y {})" ' \; ) | mail -a "FROM: Server <root@server.com>" -a "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" -s "Test" my@domain.com
```

Comment: this make no sense to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Group commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) before piping the output to `mail`.

Say:

```
{ echo "My title"; find ... \; ; } | mail ...
```

(Note that `\;` in the above command denotes the termination of command supplied to `-exec`.  The other semicolon is required to terminate the list.)

Comment: yes this works, but cron dont like it: /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @BIba cron doesn't like `%`, so you need to escape it -- `\%`

Comment: @BIba That's possibly another `cron` oddity.  The above command should work well from the command line.

Comment: ok, I missed the last ; with {} - but with () the ; is not needed.